# T-SQL Problems with query and multiple comparison

Tags: sql-server

Suppose to have this table:

```
|ORDER_NUMBER|CREATION_DATE|   STATUS   |
|201700014587|  2017-08-01 |STATUS1     |
|201700014587|  2017-08-03 |STATUS2     |
|201700013131|  2017-08-07 |STATUS1     |
|201700013131|  2017-08-11 |STATUS2     |
|201700014587|  2017-08-13 |STATUS3     |
|201700013131|  2017-08-14 |STATUS4     |
```

How can I select all orders:

1. on `STATUS1`,`STATUS2` and `STATUS4`
2. between `2017-08-01` and `2017-08-15`
3. without any rows on `STATUS3`

In this example, I would extract only order n. `201700013131`.
Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far? post some code you have tested to start with, then you will get more suggestions from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_NUMBER
    FROM YourTable T
    WHERE STATUS IN('STATUS1', 'STATUS2', 'STATUS4')
        AND CREATION_DATE BETWEEN '20170801' AND '20170815'
        AND NOT EXISTS
            (
               SELECT * FROM YourTable
                   WHERE ORDER_NUMBER = T.ORDER_NUMBER
                      AND STATUS = 'STATUS3'
            );
```

Comment: you don't need the not exists since you are already filtering the same in the in condition

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh Of course I need NOT EXISTS since the OP only wants orders where no row with STATUS3 exists.